# Django 1.1 on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am trying to get Django 1.1 working on Google App Engine.
I followed [instructions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) but, they didn't work.

I get this error message:

> ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Does it have syntax errors?): No module named settings

I bet Nick Johnson has the answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone named moraes on the #appengine channel of freenode helped me find the answer

All you have to do is put a empty 'settings.py' file in your root directory.

Comment: Why do I need an empty settings.py? Can we do this configuration completely in the file appengine_config.py instead? I suddenly need an empty settings.py and I don't think I used to need it.